# Django Models .get fails but .filter and .all works - object exists in database

Tags: python, sql, django, tdd, models

Racking my brain on this one. The model seems true, theoretically all of the commented permutations should work--- but the only things that can successfully retrieve the user is .filter and .all; .get doesnt work; I can deal with using either .filter or .all ---- but why isn't get working?

I'll reiterate that a direct SQL query works 100% in this case. All imports are in place and things are functioning great at a low level -- again, Filter works, All works, but get fails for some reason.

```
class UserModelTest(TestCase):
def test_getUserByUsername(self):
    sanity = True
    try:
        #u = User.objects.filter(username='wadewilliams')
        u = User.objects.get(username='wadewilliams')
        #u = User.objects.get(pk=15773)
        #u = User.objects.all()
    print u
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        sanity = False

    self.assertEqual(sanity, True)
```

... That test fails unless I uncomment either filter or all... both gets, no go.

And the model...

```
class User(models.Model):
    userid = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, db_column='userID')
    username = models.CharField(max_length=135)
    realname = models.CharField(max_length=150, db_column='name')
    email = models.CharField(max_length=765, blank=True)

class Meta:
    db_table = u'users'

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.username + ' (' + self.email + ')'
```

Comment: Can you add stack trace to your questions?What is the exact error message you are getting?

Comment: I created a view to try and give you the stack trace.
I created the url path and touched the view.
It ran flawlessly.

I then re-ran my unit tests... And they passed!!! I'm not sure why simply touching the view solved the unit test? So weird. Thanks for your help; Any additional explanation for this is much appreciated.

Comment: Thinking this might have been some weirdness with the unittest module?

Comment: Ok, I'm double wrong here. I omitted the test assertion. When I added that back in, the test failed, but the view still seems to work fine. 


Here is the unit test traceback..............
FAIL: test_getUserByUsername (forge.tests.users_test.UserModelTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/media/sf_host/checkouts/33/localmotors/localmotors/forge/tests/users_test.py", line 72, in test_getUserByUsername
    self.assertEqual(sanity, True)
AssertionError: False != True

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The test suite creates a mock database that is blank, so no users can be found even though the exist in the production/development database.

From the docs: 
Finding data from your production database when running tests?
If your code attempts to access the database when its modules are compiled, this will occur before the test database is set up, with potentially unexpected results. For example, if you have a database query in module-level code and a real database exists, production data could pollute your tests. It is a bad idea to have such import-time database queries in your code anyway - rewrite your code so that it doesn't do this.